# Can someone explain why my right class pops out right?

Tags: html, css

Just looking for a good explanation so that I understand why this has happened so for the future I can get it correct. Everything is fine except right class is way out right. What I don't understand is that because the headers position is fixed why does it go on top of / underneath that? Essentially what positioning makes it sit nicely where it should?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.left {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 430px;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    position: relative;

}

#footer {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've understand what you're asking for. Maybe your problem can be solved adding "top: 0; left:0;" in your header's css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `float:left` instead of `float:right`, because otherwise it will take up the container (which in this case is body) to adjust itself to the right of. Otherwise, you can increase the widths to 100%.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/K6fXE/

```
.right {
    float: left;
    ...
}
```